# Unable to send cookie using ActionCableZwei

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, cookies, websocket, actioncable

Using:

- Python 2.7.12
- Rails 5.1.2
- Ruby 2.4.1

I am using ActionCable on webpage which works fine in rails, now trying to connect from python using https://github.com/tobiasfeistmantl/python-actioncable-zwei ActionCableZwei - A Python 3 client for Rails' Action Cable

Below line connects successfully:

```
connection = Connection(url='ws://localhost:4000/cable', origin='http://localhost:4000/')
```

and I get proper logs in rails.

Now, I want to send cookies with sockets but Below line is unable to connect nor do I get any logs in rails.

```
connection = Connection(url='ws://localhost:4000/cable', origin='http://localhost:4000/', log_ping=False, cookie=coo)
```

Also tried using log_ping to True/False

Below is full code that am trying:

```
from actioncable.connection import Connection
from actioncable.subscription import Subscription
from actioncable.message import Message
import datetime
import random
from time import sleep
import Cookie 

coo = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
coo["fig"] = "newton"
coo["sugar"] = "wafer"

# connection = Connection(url='ws://localhost:4000/cable', origin='http://localhost:4000/')
connection = Connection(url='ws://localhost:4000/cable', origin='http://localhost:4000/', cookie=coo)
connection.connect()

subscription = Subscription(connection, identifier={'channel': 'TestChannel'})
subscription.create()

sleep(30)

subscription.remove()
connection.disconnect()
```

I just don't get any ping/log in rails about trying to connect. How can I fix this?